# Adding parameters to app start chain from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am using GCM to send push notifications to my Android application and when the user clicks the notification, they should be taken to a specified view in the application (For context: It's an event log).

I understand that in the simplest case, I just add some parameters to the intent that is starting the app.

However, my app requires some remote data to be available when entering my MainActivity. When starting the application normally, it's pointing to another activity, let's call it AppStartActivity. It's showing a Splash screen while downloading the neccessary data and launches MainActivity when it's ready.

When starting the app from a notification, the neccessary data may or may not be ready, depending on whether the app is currently in background (and if it has not been garbage collected). Therefore, I think I have to launch AppStartActivity when clicking the notification, and then somehow forward the Intent parameters and I'm not sure it's the right way. I have formulated some questions about this:

- Is it correct to lauch AppStartActivity with the parameters I will need in MainActivity later and then just forward them when switching to MainActivity?
- Is there a simpler way to do this, such as finding out the state of the application when clicking the notification and then choose either AppStartActivity or MainActivity depending on if the neccessary data is available? The reason I'm asking is that when I create the notification, the data may or may not be available, but it may change during the time passing before the user to interact with the notification. I understand that I can launch a new activity that is just checking the state and then launch either MainActivity or AppStartAcitivty, but it seems like it could be a bit too complicated...

I'm thankful for any input on this matter. Please let me know if I have left out some details.

Answer (score 1):

as I understand it, I had a similar situation, and this was my solution:

when I receive the GCM, my onReceive method starts a service 
for getting the remote datas. Only when these datas are
avaiable in a local content provider, I throw the notification to the user.

[edit]
You have to manage any network error with some notice, otherwise you may lose the GCM notification

Comment: Ok that sounds reasonable... However, the way my design works it won't solve the issue where the notification is clicked say 18 hours after it was presented... (My remote data might be gone by then). Might be a good answer for others though!

Comment: Saving data locally in a sqlite before they are gone is not possible in your app ?

Comment: Well it is a possibility, but not the approach I'm using. I'm storing the data in the application object. For reasons... ;)